# Read .dat file line by line in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to read from `*.dat` file in python, and my data in `*.dat` file looks like this

```
1   275 
2   264 
3   256 275 
4   194 
5   38 218 
6   98 
7   10 255 
8   157 186 
9   210 261 
10  141 
11  45 130
```

it basically has three columns and so is there any way to read them line by line or read them by column and store them into three different array ?

Comment: This link can help you http://www.101computing.net/python-reading-a-text-file/

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer this question, I would like to point out that questions that this are not the ones you should be asking in Stack Overflow. This question can be answered with a simple google search and a quick look through the docs of any machine learning library or a simple tutorial on a site like medium. Stack Overflow is the place to go when you have exhausted *all* of your most basic avenues such as googling or reading the docs of a library. This habit of exhausting all possible avenues before turning to other programmers will help you become a better programmer in the long run.

Personally, what I would do is turn the file into a data friendly file like .csv or .xlsx and then use the common machine learning library, *Pandas* to be able to parse the data.

For example: (file name is "data.csv")

```
Pregnancies,Glucose,BloodPressure,SkinThickness,Insulin,BMI,DiabetesPedigree,Age,Outcome
10,148,84,48,237,37.6,1.001,51,1
3,173,82,48,465,38.4,2.137,25,1
7,129,68,49,125,38.5,0.439,43,1
3,129,92,49,155,36.4,0.968,32,1
1,172,68,49,579,42.4,0.702,28,1
1,71,78,50,45,33.2,0.422,21,0
2,112,78,50,140,39.4,0.175,24,0
1,136,74,50,204,37.4,0.399,24,0
1,122,90,51,220,49.7,0.325,31,1
2,100,70,52,57,40.5,0.677,25,0
1,86,66,52,65,41.3,0.917,29,0
0,162,76,56,100,53.2,0.759,25,1
0,100,88,60,110,46.8,0.962,31,0
0,180,78,63,14,59.4,2.42,25,1
```

Then the relevant code to parse this line by line and put it in an array would be:

```
import pandas as pd 

#gets the path - tells the code where to look for said piece of data 
path = r"data.csv"

#creates a dataframe from the information in the path (your .csv file)
df = pd.read_csv(path)

#extract glucose column information and store it in a dataframe
glu_df = df["Glucose"]

#take the information from the dataframe and then store it in an array
glu_list = glu_df.values
```